# How do i resolve cannot find module '.' error in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

here is package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "bookworm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "easyimage": "^2.1.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.3",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.7.1",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "^0.7.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

On using npm start command its giving error about not being able to find module '.'

I can attach any logs or actual error messages if req. Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the error logs and the code where the error is thrown

Comment: Please share your server.js file instead as the current information is incomplete and error logs would not give us much information.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere your code, you're probably doing `require('.')`

Any error messages would be helpful